# How can i use the pygments make the markdown display line numbers?

Tags: markdown, highlight, jekyll, pygments

I had known the liquid highlight display line numbers。
for example:

```
{% highlight java linenos %}
    public class Test {

    }
{% endhightlight $}
```

But I don't known How should I let the markdown highlight display line numbers?

````
```java
    public class Test {

    }
```
````

Like this, it will not display line numbers.Is it should add a options parameter?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to add line numbers and formatting is to use css/javascript. Check out [Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles/index.html)

The Markdown generator will only create the html tags `<div class="highlight"><pre><code></code></pre></div>` around your content.

In the head section of your page, add a reference to the prettify script passing what parameters you need (or save the script locally in your site)

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?lang=css&skin=sunburst"></script>
```

Then use some jQuery to add the "prettyprint" class to the pre tag. That should be all you need to get prettyprint working

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(this).find( ".highlight" ).each(function(){ 
        $(this).find("pre").addClass("prettyprint"); 
    })
});

</script>
```

Choose a [theme](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles/index.html) you like, or use the defaults and add the "linenums" class to get your line numbering

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?lang=css&skin=sunburst"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(this).find("pre").not('.prettyprint').each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("prettyprint linenums");
   prettyPrint();
})
</script>
```

Your question is about using pygments. If that is what you want to use, then retain the liquid template code to let pygments mark up your code blocks and use a pygments style sheet. I personally don't like adding templates inside my posts. It may be possible configure Jekyll to use a markdown generator that generates more code friendly html, but I havn't seen it.

Comment: I'am not use the google-code-prittiry. I use the pygments. ok?

Comment: If you want to use pygments use the liquid highlight. If you choose markdown, use prettify (or some alternative)